# Cointegration testing: is there any relation between maximum lag length and the order of integration?

Tags: time-series, cointegration, lags

I have some time series and i have to check if they are cointegrated, testing each possible couple.
I have understood that the best way to go is, firstly, to verify the order of integration of all the time series. I get that each of them is integrated of order one I(1). Then, because they all have the same order of integration, i can test for cointegration. I'm using Python, in particular the functions `coint`and `coint_johansen`. My question is how should i choose the values for the parameters *maxlag* in coint and *k_ar_diff* in coint_johansen? The maximum number of lagged difference in the model is in any way related to the order of integration? Or the two concept are independent?

Comment: Hi: I can't answer with respect to python but the maximum lag length in the test for stationarity ( or lack thereof ) of the series has nothing to do with the order of integration. Usually, when testing for cointrgration the order of differencing is 1 but I imagine that it could be 2 in some weird cases.

Comment: Note that, when you test for stationarity and do say the ADF test, the ADF test is testing for  order of integration being 1 versus 0. If you wanted to test for say 2 versus 1, then you'd have to difference everything first and then do an ADF test but you probably don't need to test for integration of order 2. My point is that you can test for various orders of integration but they don't have anything to do with the maximum lag used in the ADF test.

Comment: Check out what Dave Giles has written about cointegration testing (Toda-Yamamoto procedure) in his blog. Well written and easy to follow.